# How to mount another btrfs subvolume of the filesystem that contains the root subvolume?

Tags: mount, btrfs

My `/` filesystem is located on a btrfs which contains other subvolumes I'd like to access while the system using `/` is running. I'm very certain that I used to do that using `sudo mount -o subvol=[the other subvolume] /dev/sdxY /mnt/something`. However, this now fails due to `mount: /mnt/sda2: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.`. It's possible to mount different subvolumes of a btrfs, right?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 with Linux 4.13.0-21-generic.

Comment: Did you check the correct name with `btrfs subvolume list`? Are you sure `/mnt/something` is free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the partition number `Y` in `/dev/sdxX`. Mounting as described above is possible.